# onClick not being called ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

*Before downvoting, I've been through plenty of other solutions on SO around this same issue and can't find an answer that resolves this issue.*

I'm having trouble trying to get the onClick attribute to fire off my function, here's a piece from the problematic component:

*Constructor:*

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            submissionFormCount: 0
        }
        this.addToSubmissionFormCount = this.addToSubmissionFormCount.bind(this);
    }
```

*render:*

```
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m12 l12">
                        <h5 onClick={this.addToSubmissionFormCount} style={beatSubmissionStyles.colorize}><span>(Plus) </span>add another beat</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

*clickHandler:*

```
addToSubmissionFormCount() {
        alert('Here');
        this.setState({
            submissionFormCount: this.state.submissionFormCount++
        });
    }
```

I'm rendering the app from an Express server using 'react-dom/server'

Here's how I am rendering the component:

```
exports.beatSubmission = (req, res) => {
    const appString = renderToString(<App type="beatSubmission"/>);
    res.send(beatSubmissionTemplate({
        body: appString
    }))
}
```

Comment: Other than wrapping the `<h5>` into an `<a onClick>` to improve web accessibility, the code looks OK to me.

Comment: Are you loading your app on the client side at all or all in node? Your comment about how you're rendering it using express makes me think you're not loading the client side version of the app.

Comment: @Parris I'm rendering (I believe) on the client side, the page renders properly and the markup I posted above is a child of my main App component.

Comment: @SuperCoolDude1337 I suspect you're actually only rendering on the server side actually *answer coming*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're only rendering your react components on the server side. The reason I think this is because of the following code you've copied:

```
exports.beatSubmission = (req, res) => {
    const appString = renderToString(<App type="beatSubmission"/>);
    res.send(beatSubmissionTemplate({
        body: appString
    }))
}
```

You're rendering the component to a string and shipping the string to the frontend as static HTML. While this will indeed give you properly rendered markup, it will result in a non-interactive app.

To have click handlers work, you also need to compile your JS, and include it for use on the frontend like this:

https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L76
`renderToString(<Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} store={store}/>));`

There are a few ways to do this. You can manually add a script file with your JS pre-packaged for the frontend in your template or you can use [Webpack Isomorphic Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-isomorphic-tools).

I suspect you read a react tutorial that lead you down the isomorphic (server/client side rendered) path. You can run react on the server, the client side or both. Running it on both takes some work, but results in an app that "feels" faster.

Comment: Would I have to use a store?

Comment: @SuperCoolDude1337 you could avoid using redux, stores, etc. The only important piece here is just including a JS bundle. So `webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with the code. However, the only thing that comes to my mind is if you're rendering the `<h5>` in a function of some sort, maybe mapping and array for example. If so, you need to define `var self = this` in the render function before the return, then use `self.addToSubmissionFormCount`.

P.S. I don't recommend using onClick handler in `<h5>` tag

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last note please?

Answer (score 0):

Change your h5 into an anchor tag. So replace:

`<h5 onClick={this.addToSubmissionFormCount} style={beatSubmissionStyles.colorize}><span>(Plus) </span>add another beat</h5>`

with:

`<a onClick={this.addToSubmissionFormCount} style={beatSubmissionStyles.colorize}><span>(Plus) </span>add another beat</a>`

You can style your anchor anyway you want afterwards. For example if you want to not have a cursor when hovering then add `cursor: none`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but this still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate the state of react.

Change:
this.state.submissionFormCount++
To:
this.state.submissionFormCount+1